# How to prevent an android widget from executing android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE

Tags: android, widget, broadcast

I successfully wrote a widget and it works the way i want to. I simply want to do some things when the user clicks the widget, I am updating the images inside the widget.

When I click the widget, my code runs and everything works great! However, after some seconds have passed from clicking my widget, `android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE` broadcast is ran.

I am using `onReceive()` to do all my things. Here is my pending intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, Widget.class);
    intent.setAction("CLICKED_WIDGET");
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
```

I use a custom broadcast string to signify that i am clicking the widget. This works perfectly. however, some seconds later, `android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE` gets broadcasted as well. And if i do not do anything with this broadcast, my widget is empty. So for now what i am doing is simply re-updating the widget (which is quite annoying) each time the update broadcast is sent.

What i am asking is, how can i keep that update broadcast from being sent and only update my widget when the user clicks on the widget and not any other time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so it really isn't an answer to my question exactly, as its impossible to NOT receive APPWIDGET_UPDATE broadcasts. But i found what was causing that update broadcast to be sent, in my onClick receiver, i was changing the component enable setting of a receiver and that was for some reason having the update broadcast sent. So i just moved where i change my component enabled option to my settings activity and now it works perfectly. Thanks all for viewing!